# Associate Braintree PaymentMethod with an Address

Tags: ruby, braintree

```
require 'braintree'

# set credentials
Braintree::Configuration.merchant_id = 'XXX'
Braintree::Configuration.public_key = 'YYY'
Braintree::Configuration.private_key = 'ZZZ'

Braintree::Configuration.environment = :sandbox

# see the raw messages going to and from the Braintree server
Braintree::Configuration.logger = Logger.new(STDERR)
Braintree::Configuration.logger.level = Logger::DEBUG


customer = Braintree::Customer.create!(first_name: 'John', last_name: 'Doe')

begin
  address = Braintree::Address.create!(customer_id: customer.id, locality: 'London')
  pmethod = Braintree::PaymentMethod.create(customer_id: customer.id, billing_address_id: address.id, payment_method_nonce: 'fake-valid-visa-nonce')
  p pmethod
ensure
  # always delete the Customer in order not to leave much rubbish
  # behind the testing session
  Braintree::Customer.delete(customer.id)
end
```

I create a `Customer`, than an `Address` for him. When I attempt to create a `PaymentMethod`, using a nonce representing a credit card, and provide a billing address (by means of an ID of the previously saved `Address`), the `PaymentMethod` is not saved and error result is returned. The `p pmethod` line prints

```
#<Braintree::ErrorResult params:{...} errors:<credit_card:[(91701) Cannot provide both a billing address and a billing address ID.]>>
```

The error message doesn't make sense, as I only provide billing address ID. I have also checked that the SDK doesn't e.g. forge an empty address and send it to the server together with the `PaymentMethod` data provided in my code.

Creating a `PaymentMethod` without billing address works, but I really want to specify one.

Comment: What is in the params? `params:{...}`?

Comment: @jamesw `{:payment_method=>{:customer_id=>"75850275", :billing_address_id=>"jh", :payment_method_nonce=>"fake-valid-visa-nonce"}, :controller=>"payment_methods", :action=>"create", :merchant_id=>"XXXXXX"}`

Comment: That `:billing_address_id=>"jh"` looks suspicious to me. Might be the cause cause of your issues

Comment: @jamesw `params` simply contain what was sent to the server. `"jh"` is ID of the `Address` object created first. There is nothing suspicious about it. (Address IDs in Braintree look like this.)

Comment: I can see nothing wrong with your code. Of course that doesn't mean there isn't. Perhaps a bug? Maybe report it to the Gem develppers, see what they say?, maybe you are not on a stable branch? Just kicking ideas around.

Comment: @jamesw The response is generated on the server, not in the gem. The gem is only a thin wrapper over an API. (And the question is rather a question for someone who has plenty of experience with Braintree than for someone able to kick around general "Ruby ideas".)

Comment: Is it not the gem that passes the information to the server? (6 years of payment gateway experience but I'll  leave you to it!) Good luck

Answer (score 2, accepted):

<sub>Full disclosure: I work at Braintree. If you have any further questions, feel free to contact [support](https://support.braintreepayments.com/).</sub>

Bottom-line: At this time, you cannot test the `billing_address_id` with a [test nonce](https://developers.braintreepayments.com/reference/general/testing/ruby#payment-method-nonces), but it will work with [a nonce generated for the sandbox from a Drop-in or Custom Integration at the client side](https://developers.braintreepayments.com/start/overview#payment-method-nonce).

This is a limitation of the testing API itself. When you submit one of the test nonces, it pre-populates with data that is commonly required for various checks. One of those pre-populated fields is that of `billing_address=>zip_code` which you can see if you do a vanilla payment method create with the fake nonce you are using. `billing_address` can be overwritten with whatever test values you want, but you can't undo it or zero it out.

Comment: I have tried this without a test nonce (hosted fields), and it also doesn't accept the billingAddressId  - is there a way to actually test this in the sandbox? Don't want it to create new addresses ...